# Generalization of MPI rank number to MPI groups?

Tags: mpi

Is there any generalization of rank number to group numbers? For my code I would like to create a hierarchical decomposition of MPI::COMM_WORLD. Assume we make use of 16 threads. I use MPI::COMM_WORLD.Split to create 4 communicators each having 4 ranks. Is there now an MPI function that provides some unique ids to the corresponding four groups?

Answer (score 5):

Well, you can still refer to each process by its original rank in `MPI_COMM_WORLD`. You also have complete control over what rank each process receives in its new communicator via the `color` and `key` arguments of `MPI_Comm_split()`. This is plenty enough information to create a mapping between old ranks and new groups/ranks.

Comment: You are right, the information I add to `MPI_Comm_split()` is enough to compute the information I asked for. But it's not trivial to do it in the case of 10.000 of cores. That's the reason I asked if there is a support for doing this directly on the base of MPI.

Comment: Seems simple enough to me. If you have N*M processes that you want to split into M groups of N, then each process calls `Split()` with `rank / N` color (and optionally, `rank % N` key). This will place ranks 0..N-1 into group 0, N..2*N-1 into group 1, and so forth, and preserve the original ordering of processes within each group. The process with rank `i` in group `j` is the one with rank `j*N+i` in `MPI_COMM_WORLD`.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't like @suszterpatt's answer (I do) you could always abuse a Cartesian communicator and pretend that the process at index (2,3) in the communicator is process 3 in group 2 of your hierarchical decomposition.

But don't read this and take away the impression that I recommend such abuse, it's just a thought.